# ConTeXt: Styling pagenumbers in registers

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I'm using some `description` paragraphs as definitions for some concepts. I want to add them to my register and typeset their pagenumbers in bold numbers (to recognize where is the definition).

The wiki puts an example:

```
\defineregister[nickname][nicknames]
\setupregister [nickname][foto][pagestyle=bold]

\starttext
And text about Kuba\nickname[foto::]{Kuba}.
\completenickname
\stoptext
```

But, as you see, it only puts the word under the F letter. I tried with processors too, but it turns bold the word rather than pagenumber. I suspect the manual is outdated in this part too, but I don't know how to do this... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MkIV register formatting is handled differently.
Like in the legacy version, both page numbers and entry text can be
assigned a style to highlight certain entries.
However, where MkII lets you specify sub-styles that are local to a
register, the current version provides the more generic **processors**.

A processor is defined globally and can be applied to entries of
different lists.
Also, the separation between *pagestyle* and *textstyle* has been
removed, which had been redundant anyways.
Processors follow the pattern of
[style alternatives](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Style_Alternatives)
instead and can be configured through the usual `style` and `color`
options.
Finally, “`->`” replaces the double colon as operator for style
application.
The
[wiki page on registers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Registers#Processors)
now has a description of processors with examples.

```
%% step 1: define a register (no plural in MkIV!)
\defineregister [nickname] [style=\WORD\bold,pagestyle=normal]

%% step 2: define a style processor
\defineprocessor [relevant] [style=bold,color=red]

%% step 2a: works with custom styles, too
\definealternativestyle [neato] [\bfb]
\defineprocessor [weird] [style=neato]

\starttext
  \title{List of Known Nicknames}
  \placenickname
  \page

  \page text \nickname{foo}
  \page text \nickname{bar}
  \page text \nickname{baz}
%% step 3: use in text
  \page text \nickname[relevant->]{foo}
  \page text \nickname{bar}
  \page text \nickname{baz}
  \page text \nickname{foo}
  \page text \nickname[weird->]{bar}
  \page text \nickname{baz}
  \page text \nickname{foo}
  \page text \nickname{bar}
  \page text \nickname[relevant->]{baz}
\stoptext
```

[image: demo of register entry processors]